# Update statement is not working in for Loop

Tags: sql, plsql

I need one quick help from people. I have one procedure which is updating some records in table.but inside Loop update statement is not executing although it is fetching records in cursor.

I have tried to put dbms_output.put_line in statement but it not printing.

```
  CURSOR cur_or
  IS
  SELECT DISTINCT c.general_ledger_gid,
                  b.order_release_gid --, c.cost_type
    FROM invoice_shipment a,
         view_shipment_order_release b,
         shipment_cost c
   WHERE a.shipment_gid      = b.shipment_gid
     AND c.shipment_gid        = c.shipment_gid
     AND a.shipment_gid        = c.shipment_gid
     AND a.invoice_gid         = p_invoice_gid
     AND c.general_ledger_gid IS NOT NULL;

  CURSOR cur_orl (lv_ORDER_RELEASE_GID IN VARCHAR2)
  IS
  SELECT d.order_release_line_gid
    FROM order_release_line d
   WHERE order_release_gid = lv_ORDER_RELEASE_GID;

BEGIN
  FOR rec_or IN cur_or
  LOOP
    UPDATE allocation_order_release_d
    SET general_ledger_gid    = rec_or.general_ledger_gid
    WHERE general_ledger_gid IS NULL
    AND order_release_gid     = rec_or.order_release_gid;

    dbms_output.put_line ('a Passed');
    FOR rec_orl IN cur_orl (rec_or.order_release_gid)
    LOOP
      UPDATE allocation_or_line_d
      SET general_ledger_gid     = rec_or.general_ledger_gid
      WHERE general_ledger_gid  IS NULL
      AND order_release_line_gid = rec_orl.order_release_line_gid;

      dbms_output.put_line ('b Passed');
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line ('c Passed');
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line ('d Passed');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
```

It should run the update statement inside loop as cursor is fetching values

Comment: Not answers, but thoughts: Regarding the dbms_output statements, have you enabled serveroutput in your client?  I suggest you use indentation to make your code more readable.  It looks to me that the exception handler is unnecessary (nothing in that code should ever throw NO_DATA_FOUND).

Comment: Records in cursor CUR_OR does not imply that there are records in table ALLOCATION_ORDER_RELEASE_D.    
Records in cursor CUR_ORL does not imply that there are records in table ALLOCATION_OR_LINE_D.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I had checked there are records in ALLOCATION_ORDER_RELEASE_D and ALLOCATION_OR_LINE_D. Could you please confirm that the Loop statement is right or not?

Comment: plsql executed successfully?? no runtime errors? if no issues on runtime and ocmpleted successfully, then check the cursor select statements where they  returning value or not. if they return value, check the where clasuse of the update statements as select statement whether they are returning any records or not